# Will the creation of an iterator_traits<InIter>::value_type trigger a deference when passed? (Exception testing)

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, boost, iterator

I'm having trouble purposely throwing exceptions(for testing purposes) for functions that do not specifically deference iterators. To get an idea of what I am doing, take my `decorator_iterator` struct:

```
struct decorated_iterator
      : boost::iterator_adaptor<
            decorated_iterator<BaseIterator, IteratorTag>,
            BaseIterator, boost::use_default, IteratorTag>
    {
        //....
    private:
        friend class boost::iterator_core_access;

        /* used to throw an exception upon dereference */
        typename base_type::reference dereference() const
        {
            m_callback();
            return *(this->base());
        }

    private:
        std::function<void()> m_callback;
    };
```

`decorator_iterator` lets me attach callbacks to an iterator that are triggered on dereference, using this I can test exception throwing with

```
try {

    copy(
        decorated_iteartor(iter, [](){throw std::runtime_error("test");}),
        decorated_iterator(iter, [](){}),
        begin(destiter));
}
//catch runtime!
```

this function works great for some of my implementations that specifically dereference a pointer e.g.

```
[](reference it) {
    //triggers callback
    *it = ...
}
```

my problem now is when I'm working on a parallel implementation of `std::count`, all of my exception tests fail. My guess is that I never specifically dereference an iterator in my lambda function, and instead use `iterator_traits<InIter>::value_type`. If value type won't dereference, what can I modify in either `decorator_iterator` or my function to cause callback to be executed? the specific count overload that is giving me trouble:

```
template <typename ExPolicy, typename InIter, typename T>
typename detail::algorithm_result<ExPolicy, 
    typename std::iterator_traits<InIter>::difference_type>::type
count(ExPolicy const& policy, InIter first, InIter last, const T& value,
boost::mpl::false_ f)
{
    //get a value_type to compare to passed value
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<InIter>::value_type type;
    typename std::iterator_traits<InIter>::difference_type ret = 0;

    //from first to last, execute the following lambda
    for_each_n(policy,
        first, std::distance(first,last),
        [&value, &ret](type v) {
            if (v == value)
                ret++;
        }, f);

    return detail::algorithm_result<ExPolicy, 
        typename std::iterator_traits<InIter>::difference_type>::get(std::move(ret));

}
```

note: I tried simply modifying the lambda to pass in a `InIter ref` and using `*ref` but that will not work and will give me errors.

Comment: As soon as the algorithm goes to dereference the value, (either `*it` or `it->`), it should be hitting that function.  Using `value_type` vs. `reference` as the argument to the lambda just influences if it's going to make a copy.

Comment: What is this for_each_n function where the problem happen ? You don't have the callback triggered, but is it working ?

Comment: If this is about the n3554 proposal, please link to the relevant prototype implementation?

Comment: Does the library propagate exceptions from other threads?

Answer (score 0):

Iterators only afford a well-defined set of operations.

I'm not aware of any other (well-defined) method of dereferencing an iterator except by using the standard-defined dereference operation (indirection operator, or `*it`).

You could see implementations that optimize for e.g. std::vector::iterator, (e.g. using a memcpy/memmov if the element type is POD). However I think it would be **a bad idea** for a library (in this case your parallel algorithms library) to make such assumptions about user-suppplied iterators. In other words, if the library detects the base-iterator type and optimizes for it in such a way that it *bypasses* the side-effect of the user-defined iterator, that **would be a severe bug** in my opinion.

Thinking out of the box, an explanation could be that exceptions are not propagated (immediately) from the worker threads. I don't know what `ExPolicy` is, but it could be am exception policy.

I can fully imagine that the algorithm returns a `future<size_t>` (perhaps depending on the `ExPolicy` parameter) and therefore you don't see the exception **until you `.get()`** the value of the future?